# Error: Invalid start tag LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

So, I thought to make my app compatible with tablets, so I copied my xml's to the values-sw600dp folder, but I get this error Invalid start tag LinearLayout. Can you guys tell me what did I do wrong? I get the error where this line is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: just clean & build your project

Comment: add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> before your linearlayout tag

Answer (score 2):

You have a layout file in the wrong folder (ie: in values-sw600dp instead of layout-sw600dp)

Answer (score 0):

Put layouts into res/layout-sw600dpi folder then

1. Clean
2. Build

your xml should be working again.

Comment: Error: Invalid start tag LinearLayout

Comment: I don't get that error anymore, but I still don't know if this is going to work for tablets. :)

Comment: well, just adjust your layouts for tablet as well before using it in my opinion, if it's android studio, it'll show you how it will look in this attributes as preview.

Comment: No no, that was premature. I get now "the import....R cannot be resolved". I had to delete those xml from that folder. :(

Comment: what xml files did you put into that folder? strings.xml, color.xml as well?